# i want to trigger a click event with span tag but not responding

Tags: html, jquery

i want to hide image on clicking a span button but not responding
it has a class of close

```
$('.close').on('click', function(){
        $('.img-wrap').empty();
        $('#commentfile').val(null);
  });
```

this is the html file

```
<div class="img-wrap"><span class="close">×</span>
   <img id="preview" class="comment-preview mb-1" src="blob:http://localhost/d778f234-1c6f-4145-b9cb-5267cce10e34" alt="...">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine when replicated in a codepen, adding in the jQuery CDN. It's likely that the issue stems from you not having jQuery in your project or a poor implementation.

Comment: I've created a codepen here: https://codepen.io/brayden-merrifield/pen/WNrqpmj

It works as expected, do note that the codepen has the jQuery CDN in the settings.